# Show that $Tr(A)$ is in the spectrum of $A+I$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

If we have $p$ an odd prime number and the matrix $A$ $(p×p)$ with rational entries and we know that $\det(A^{p}+I)=0$, $\det(A+I)≠0$. How we can show $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is in the spectrum of $A+I$?
I know we need to use the fact that the minimal polynomial divides the cyclotomic polynomial which is irreductible over Q. But I dont know how to extract that Information from the determinant. Yes we can say that $\det(A^{p-1}-A^{p-2}+...-A+I)=0$. But I dont know how to use the minimal polynomial here. Can someone explain me?

Comment: It seems to me that $A$ does not exist. If $x^p+1=(x+1)\Phi_p(-x)$ annihilates $A$ and $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be equal to $\Phi_p(-x)$ because $\Phi_p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. Hence the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be $\Phi_p(-x)^k$ for some $k$, but this is impossible because $\deg\Phi_p=p-1<p<2(p-1)=\deg\Phi_p^2$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RamenNii-chan I think the minimal polynomial must have the cyclotomic polynomial and 1 degree irreductible factor, because the degree of the characteristic polynomial is p and from Frobenius they need to share the same irreductible factors.

Comment: @RamenNii-chan What we have is that $\det(A^p+I)=0$, not that $A^p+I=0$. That is, $A^p+I=(A+I)\Phi_p(-A)$ is singular. Since $A+I$ is nonsingular, $\Phi_p(-A)$ must be singular, but this doesn't mean that $\Phi_p(-A)=0$. Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{q\\ &C}$ where $q$ is an arbitrary rational number and $C$ is the companion matrix of $\Phi_p(-x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A+I$ is nonsingular but $A^p+I=(A+I)\Phi_p(-A)$ is singular, $\Phi_p(-A)$ must be singular. If $\Phi_p(-x)$ and the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $A$ are relatively prime, we would have $a(x)\Phi_p(-x)+b(x)m(x)=1$ for some polynomials $a,b\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and in turn $a(A)\Phi_p(-A)=I$, which is a contradiction. Hence $\Phi_p(-x)$ must share an irreducible factor with $m(x)$.

As $\Phi_p(-x)$ is already irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, it must divide $m(x)$. However, as $\deg\Phi_p(-x)<p<\deg\Phi_p(-x)^2$, $m(x)$ cannot possibly be equal to any power of $\Phi_p(-x)$. So, we must have $m(x)=(x-q)\Phi_p(-x)$ for some $q\in\mathbb Q$. But then $m(x)$ is also the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(A)=$ sum of all zeroes of $m$ $=q+1$. Yet, as $q$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $q+1$ is an eigenvalue of $A+I$. Hence the result follows.

Comment: Can we say that if $P$ is irreductible polynomial and $det(P(A))=0$, then $P$ divides the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @StefanSolomon Yes, for the same reason in my answer: since $p(A)$ is singular, $p$ and the minimal polynomial $m$ cannot possibly be coprime. Hence they share a common irreducible factor. However, as $p$ is already irreducible, it must divide $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_p$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, so that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
P_A(X)=(X-a_1)(X-a_2)\dots(X-a_p)\ .
$$
The matrix $A+I$ has eigenvalues $a_1+1,a_2+1,\dots,a_p+1$, and no entry is zero, so $-1$ is not among $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_p$.

The matrix $A^p+I$ has eigenvalues $a_1^p+1,a_2^p+1,\dots,a_p^p+1$, and at least one entry is zero, so at least one entry among $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_p$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
Q(X)=
\frac{X^p+1}{X+1}
=X^{p-1}-X^{p-2}+\dots+X^2-X+1\ .
$$
Which is irreducible, it is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{2p}$ of order $2p$ and degree $\varphi(2p)=2p\left(1-\frac 12\right)\left(1-\frac 1p\right)
=p-1$.

We may and do assume that $a_1$ is a root of $Q$.
Then using the action of the corresponding Galois group, from $0=P_A(a_1)$, and $P_A\in\Bbb Q[X]$, for each Galois substitution $\sigma$ we have also
$0=\sigma(0)=\sigma(\ P_A(a_1)\ )=P_A(\ \sigma(a_1)\ )$, so all conjugates $\sigma(a_1)$ are also roots of $P_A$. In other words, $Q$ divides $P_A$. The quotient $P_A/Q$ has degree one, and lives over $\Bbb Q$, let $b\in\Bbb Q\ne -1$ be its root, so we have:
$$
P_A(X)=Q(X)(X-b)\ ,
$$
and the trace of $A$ is the sum of its eigenvalues, i.e. trace of $Q$ plus $b$,
$$
\operatorname{Trace}(A)=
1+b\ .
$$
Which is an eigenvalue of $I+A$, since $b$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

$\square$

---

Note: $A$ is diagonalizable, $A=SDS^{-1}$, with a base change matrix $S$, and $D$ diagonal, and on its diagonal there are the $(p-1)$  (different) roots of $Q$, the primitive (non-real) roots of order $2p$ of the unit, and the rational (real) entry $b$.